# Remove empty items from my array and remove selected item when checkbox checked in react

Tags: arrays, reactjs, checkbox

```
const [person, setPerson] = useState(
        {
            name: "",
            age: "",
            school: "",
            address: "",
            telephone: "",

        }
    );
```

I want to remove the (telephone) when checkbox checked and also want to remove empty values from my array and thing is if any value is empty I wanna remove entire -> (telephone: "") from my array

Comment: What's wrong with just setting the value to `null`/`undefined` and then having the application code just work with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For removing one item from your person object you can try:

```
handleCheckboxChange (value) {
  if (value === true) {
      const {telephone, ...state} = person;
      setPerson(state);
  }
}
```

For removing the empty items:

```
handleInputChange() {
  // an array of non-empty fields
  const fields = Object.entries(person).filter([key, value] => !!value);

  // create state object from entries
  const state = Object.fromEntries(fields);

  setPerson(state);
}
```

**BUT...** With hooks, it's recommended to break the state into several pieces, like this:

```
const [personName, setPersonName] = useState('');
const [personAge, setPersonAge] = useState('');
...
```

The benefits are:

1. You get the flexibility to change them independantly.
2. You don't need to merge object each time you want to set the state.

Checkout this react doc: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html#tip-using-multiple-state-variables

Answer (score 0):

use delete to remove variable from object

```
const newPerson=person;

if(newPerson.telephone===''){
 delete newPerson.telephone;
}

...otherchecks

setPerson(newPerosn)
```